# How to find that the map was downloaded successfully? [android]

Tags: android, google-maps

people, 
I need to know if there is any way to check if the map is being shown on the phone.

For example: When I'm connected to a wi-fi that does not transmit data. For this example, it is shown only a square (since I had no internet to download).

Would like to know if the map is being displayed completely?

Thank's!

Comment: what about [GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback.html)

**This event will not fire if the map never loads due to connectivity issues, or if the map is continuously changing and never completes loading due to the user constantly interacting with the map.**

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to know if the map tiles have been downloaded, you can however check and see if there is an internet connection which you can then assume tiles are being downloaded

Comment: Thank's. 
I'll try to do this check!